# Countdown in program while not opened

Tags: python

i have no idea how to do it but i want to run a script every 24hrs. So for example if i open it at 8pm i wont be able to open it again for the next 24hrs so i have to wait for the next day and im able to open it again at 8pm the next day. Every response is appreciated.

I tried it with a text file but that didnt really work since you had to open the file at the exact same time or hour. Also you were able to just edit the text file.

i tried to do it with a txt file where it prints the time but that is not really working since you have to open the file at the exact same time.

Comment: All you need is a text file that stores the date and time, or even the integer timestamp, of the last open.  Then you read the file, and if time.time() is less than 86400 seconds from then, don't allow the open.

Answer (score -1):

Have you heard of [CRON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)?
You can use it to schedule the script to run once every 24 hrs.

eg. Lets say you have a script to run called `script.py`

Open your crontab file `crontab -e [username]` and add the following line

`0 0 * * * python script.py`

This will cause your machine to execute your script once every 24 hrs.

Reference:
https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215767047-Creating-a-custom-Cron-Job

Comment: This does not address the requirement as described in the OP.